# Why isn't Gnome 3  working on 12.04 in VMWare Player?

Tags: gnome, virtualization, vmware

After I installed Gnome 3, restarted, and logged back in with "Gnome" as the chosen interface. My desktop looks like this. Any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- From the screenshot, I see you are running Ubuntu in VMWare Player (on Windows).
- What's probably happening is that Gnome isn't detecting 3D acceleration/support and is falling back to Gnome 2D (which looks exactly like your screenshot).
- VMWare Player does have rudimentary 3D support, but *it needs to be enabled* from the settings first; [see the below screenshot](http://www.eightforums.com/virtualization/4422-windows-8-under-vmware-player-better-graphics-performance-possible.html):

  [image]
- If you can't find that option in the settings, add this line to the `.vmx` file:

  ```
  mks.enable3D = "TRUE"
  ```
- Then restart VMWare player, boot Ubuntu, select Gnome and hopefully you'll get Gnome-Shell (3D).

Comment: izx, thanks for your immediate response. I am unable to locate a ".vmx" file; however, I see a ".vmxf" file in the Documents/Virutal Machines directory.

For some reason, the options to select 3D Graphics and Monitors in the Display option is greyed out, so I can't change any of the settings.